# Script for in-place processing of iostat for aggregate rMB/s

Tags: bash, awk, filesystems

On RHEL-6.8 machine, I am trying to collect iostat every few seconds
(say 5 seconds) on specific disk volumes. Is there a way in-place 
processing of this continuous stream to get aggregate "rMB/s" on all the
specific disk volumes ?

I am looking for shell script or python script.

For instance: I run iostat as below.

```
cpuNram # iostat -dmx SVM28000 SVM28001 SVM28002 SVM28003 5

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util

SVM28000        10.60     0.00   21.97    4.07     1.66     0.09   137.49     0.05    2.07    0.31   11.55   0.94   2.44

SVM28001        10.49     0.00   21.65    3.15     1.64     0.08   142.45     0.04    1.80    0.31   12.03   0.78   1.95

SVM28002        10.96     0.00   22.40    3.06     1.71     0.08   144.43     0.04    1.70    0.31   11.86   0.76   1.94

SVM28003        10.70     0.00   22.09    3.05     1.67     0.08   142.88     0.05    1.87    0.32   13.09   0.83   2.09

cpuNram #
```

I like to see the sum of rMB/s for all the volumes. In this example, 6.68 rMB/s (1.66 + 1.64 + 1.71 + 1.67).

I tried:

```
cpuNram # iostat -dmx SVM28000 SVM28001 SVM28002 SVM28003 | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 | awk '{s+=$6} END {print s}'
6.68      ----> this is the aggregate I am looking for
cpuNram #
```

But the moment I add time interval to iostat, it does not output anything:

```
cpuNram # iostat -dmx SVM28000 SVM28001 SVM28002 SVM28003 5 | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 | awk '{s+=$6} END {print s}'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  "Anything's possible in an animated cartoon." -Bugs Bunny  Put that in a loop with a 5-second delay, and process the output inside the loop.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for free coding services, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, and libraries, are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Step 1- create an input file of sample iostat output to test your awk script on. Once that works move on to Step 2 - test it with that input piped from your other commands. After all of that if you're having problems then google "buffering" and "stdbuf".

Comment: @EdMorton - am I reading this wrong?  I thought it was a buffering issue, not an awk "haaaaaaalp"" per se.

Comment: @stevesliva I think it almost certainly is a buffering issue but AFAIK the OP hasn't yet tried running the script (or pipeline) against the output of the command when saved in a file so just want to eliminate the other possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
iostat -dmx SVM28000 SVM28001 SVM28002 SVM28003 5 | awk '/^SVM/ && buf < 4 {buf++; agg += $6} buf == 4 {print agg; agg = buf = 0}'
```

**buf** controls how many lines you're aggregating, in your case they are 4. So while the buffer is not full, you add the value of $6 to agg.

When the buffer is full, print the aggretated and reset the variables to start again.

Comment: Yes, this works on my machine as well. Thanks @valrog.

Comment: BTW, I modified iostat source code, to print the aggregate. But that needs new iostat install.